# Reading CSV files into a 2D vector

Tags: c++, csv, file, multidimensional-array, 2d-vector

The contents of my file look like:

```
Barr,3145,7
Rab,12,5513,1412,221,232,179,7121231
Bean,1,1231,219,21,337,9239,312,764,640391,4,7966346,22278,5,116364,56350
Earl,132,230,121,32,425,67
Donut,112,5525,23121,2123,65432,8790,3,4567,444
```

I want each line to be stored in a 2D vector `(vector<vector<string>>)` without the comma.

I have tried doing:

```
while(getline(filestream, line)){   
    stringstream linestream(line);
    while(getline(linestream, anotherLine, ','){
        oneDvector.push_back(anotherLine);  
    }
    twoDvector.push_back(oneDvector);
    oneDvector.clear();
}
```

But this does not seem to work. What can I do?

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Do you get a compile error, or wrong output? Please describe the issue exactly and add a [mre]

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you don't want to use a 2d vector or array.  You want a `std::vector` of a class:

```
struct Record
{
    std::string    text;
    std::vector<int> data;

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
    std::string  text_line;
    std::getline(input, text_line);
    std::istringstream text_stream(text_line);
    std::getline(text_stream, r.text, ',');
    int value;
    char comma;
    while (text_stream >> value)
    {
        r.data.push_back(value);
        text_stream >> comma;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Note:  In the above input function, a record is read by line into a string.  This will make the reading of the numbers easier.

You input loop could look like:

```
Record r;
std::vector<Record> database;
while (file_stream >> r)
{
    database.push_back(r);
}
```

Usually modeling a structure from an input record makes a better program.  Easier to develop and debug.

The input may be simplified by replacing the 2nd occurrence and remaining commas with spaces.  The first comma is used to end the text field.

Comment: Are you resetting the file pointer with each structure?  If you open the file once, read each "line" into the vector, then close when complete, you should not be seeing the result you describe.

Comment: Yup I got that. I still don't understand why we are returning another stream object reference. It's working for me, but I'd like to understand C++'s working here.

Comment: The return of the `std::istream` is to allow for *chaining*, example:  `std::cout << 5 << "hello\n";`